# How can I add i18n in an input plaeholder?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I have some inputs with placeholders. like that:

```
<input placeholder="Filter">
```

But, I have to respect the i18n method.
**i18n-placeholder** is not allowed with **Angular 6**

What is the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
placeholder="{{ 'Filter'| translate }}"
```

Comment: thanks for response! I followed this tutorial https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular6-app-with-ngx-translate but an error remains in place "unresolved pipe translate"

Comment: the error is "The pipe 'translate' could not be found"

Comment: Thank you, your response resolved my issue. I import TranslateModule in my src/reusables/reusables.module.ts and change, in package.json, "rxjs": from "^6.5.2" to "6.0.0"